# Does interpretation affect the conditional probability distribution function?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Suppose X and Y are independent standard normal random variables. We are finding the conditional probability distribution function (pdf) of Y given Y=X.

However, there can be different interpretations of the problem.
The given fact Y=X can be interpreted as (i) Z=0, where Z=Y-X or (ii) Z=1 where Z=X/Y, or (iii) Z=1 where Z=I(Y=X) (I is the index function)

My professor says that the pdf of Y given Y=X will vary with the interpretation of the condition Y=X. I could not really understand why.

What I could understand till now is this:

I will have different distributions of Z according to the interpretation. In case (i), it will be normal with parameters (0,2). In case (ii), it will be a Cauchy distribution and I don't know about (iii).

Coming back to the point, as I change the interpretation, the $f_Z(z)$ (pdf of random variable Z) changes and so, since the conditional pdf of Y|Z=z is $\frac{f_Y(.)}{f_Z(.)}$, it will also change.
Now my question is this:

(1) Will the probability of occurrence of a certain value change with our interpretation?

(2) Will the conditional expectation change with our interpretation?

I think it should not change. But I am unable to reason it out why. Can anyone please help me with this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The _random variables_ $X$ and $Y$ cannot at the same time be independent _and_ also $X=Y$. The _event_ $\{X=Y=a\}$ for some real number $a$ is conceivable, but then there is no "conditional distribution" to derive since both involved random variables are fixed per the conditioning statement.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos That's an interesting argument, but how about this experiment: What's the probability distribution function of highest marks in a class given that the highest marks this year are equal to the highest marks obtained last year. Here we don't know the highest marks obtained last year and that preserves the uncertainty, I suppose. Am I going in wrong direction? Please correct me. Thanks!

Comment: If by assumption the two random variables are independent, then the fact that a specific realization of the one was identical to the specific realization of the other, changes nothing, and the "conditional" distribution of $Y$ given this fact is just the marginal distribution of $Y$.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos I agree on this with you. I have even tried to calculate the conditional probability distribution function of Y and it came out to be same as marginal distribution function. Perhaps my presumption of the pdf changing is wrong. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: You 're welcome.